# Zend Studio for eclipse - Switch character encoding for all files in a project

Tags: eclipse, character-encoding, zend-studio

I'm using Zend Studio for Eclipise on Mac, and it seems to keep setting all files to have and encoding of 'Mac Roman'. This becomes problematic when I save the files, as they all need to be UTF-8.

I know how to change the encoding to UTF-8 on a file by file basis, but I was wondering if I could set this project wide?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Eclipse-Wide: Window->Preferences->Appearence->Workspace
- Project-Wide: Rightclick on Project->Properties
- Filewide: Rightclick on File->Properties

Answer (score 5):

On my Eclipse for PHP Helios SR 2 for Mac:

- Eclipse-Wide: Eclipse->Preferences->General->Workspace

The others are the same as @SkaveRat

Answer (score 2):

On a Zend Studio 8.x,for Mac osx 10.5.8 I changed it like this:

Top menu chose: `Edit`->`Set encoding`->`Other: UTF-8,`. By default it is set Mac Roman.

And then apply.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember, php does not actually support utf-8 encoded sourcefiles.
When creating strings in a utf-8 encoded file, php will just see 2 static bytes per character.

Try running the following with either utf-8 or ISO-8859-1 enconding. 
strlen() will report different lengths depending on encoding.

```
<?php
$string = "äüö";
echo (strlen($string));
?>
```

Comment: That's irrelevant. PHP can handle UTF-8 (as long as the damn Eclipse doesn't screw it up), you just need to use mb_* functions instead.