# UTF8 -- still showing weird characters?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

My webpage's response headers show this:

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

However, I still get a black diamond with white question mark for characters like `é`. What am I supposed to do exactly? It's my .htaccess that's setting UTF-8.

Comment: `Content-Type` only lets browser understand how to decode the content; it's your responsibility to encode it correctly.

Comment: I'm using Zend Studio. Are you saying that might be the culprit?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding

Comment: Your data is encoded in ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252, but you serve it as UTF-8. Note that the header is only a hint to the browser, it does't make your data magically utf-8. If the hint is wrong, you get garbage like the black diamond unicode replacement character in this case.

Comment: Read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a script or HTML file, check the encoding of the file itself, which should be saved as UTF-8.

In Zend, its something like: `Edit->Set encoding->Other: UTF-8,`

Comment: Is this a global solution? Do do I need to go through my hundreds of files and re-saved them?

Comment: Ah, you could try this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755245/zend-studio-for-eclipse-switch-character-encoding-for-all-files-in-a-project

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving a HTML page you need to indicate in the HTML file that the content is UTF-8. 
You can do this by adding a meta html tag to your header section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```